# Wiki engine for D&D

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, tools

I'm serching for wiki engine, preferably written on python(but is not necessary), with one specific feature - user should be able to insert the block on pages, which will be visible only for one user, the author. This wiki is needed to play dungeons and dragons. Dungeon master should be able to insert a mark for himself.

Comment: I changed your tags since the question is about GM tools and not about D&D.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Unfortunately resource recommendation questions typically make poor stack exchange questions. I've voted to close this question for that reason. However, I do hope that you will stick around. Have a look at our [FAQ] or check out meta if you have any questions. Again welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moinmoin](http://moinmo.in/) would fit that bill pretty well. It has [hierarchical ACL](http://moinmo.in/HierarchicalAccessControlList) which can do just what you want and is written in Python.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using another website, [Obsidian Portal](http://obsidianportal.com) has exactly what you want.